# What am i doing wrong with PHP in_array() function, It is not returning desired values

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with PHP in_array() method, it is quite simple but not working as it should. I've tried many solutions from the internet. But everything seems okay. Can you please help me find a mistake in my syntax or logic

Here is my code

```
$array1 = array('1','0.2','1.3','0.6','1.4','1.6','12','1.2','11.2');
$array2 = [];
for($i=0.1; $i<=15;){
    $array2[] = $i;
    $i+= 0.1;
}

foreach($array2 as $key=>$value){
    // print_r($array1);
    if(in_array($value, $array1)){
        echo $value. ' OK <br>';
    }else{
        echo $value. '<br>';
    }
    
}
```

Here is my output image
[image]

Red Highlighted text is returned true and green is not returning

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why do you compare numbers to strings?

Comment: yes i've tried, but not returning any error. Actually i've tried it with a numeric float value in $array1 @NicoHaase

Comment: **What** have you tried? What exactly do you expect?

Comment: Debugging isn't just about finding error messages, it's about finding the logical issues in your code too

Comment: Don't blame PHP (title) when it is your fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use numbers or strings but not compare numbers to strings and hope that they will be the same. An easy fix would be to use `strval` to convert the generated number to a string in the comparison test

```
<?php

    $array1 = array('1','0.2','1.3','0.6','1.4','1.6','12','1.2','11.2');

    $array2 = [];
    for($i=0.1; $i<=15; $i+= 0.1 )$array2[] = $i;


    foreach($array2 as $key=>$value){

        if( in_array( strval($value),  $array1 )){
            echo $value. ' OK <br>';
        }else{
            echo $value. '<br>';
        }
        
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must compare a string array with a string, add a conversion before comparing or while you're initializing your second array.

This will solve your issue :

```
$array1 = array('1','0.2','1.3','0.6','1.4','1.6','12','1.2','11.2');
$array2 = [];
$i = 0.1;
while( $i <= 15 ) :
    $array2[] = strval( $i );
    $i = $i + 0.1;
endwhile;

foreach($array2 as $value){
    // print_r($array1);
    if(in_array($value, $array1)){
        echo $value. ' OK <br>';
    }else{
        echo $value. '<br>';
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please explaine always your answer.

Comment: Thanks, strval() solve my problem. Thanks a lot.